# GnuWin32 sed how can I search and replace quotes? Win7 UK

Tags: windows-7, sed

Getting really weird behaviour with sed in Win7:
Manual says surround substitute command with single quote (') - rejects, only allows double quote (").
Plus I want to change double quote in a file to another char

- sed "s/"/Q/" - result unknown option
- sed "s/\"/Q/" - result invalid argument
- sed "s/'/Q/" - result no change
- sed "s/\'/Q/" - result adds "Q" to end of line  - treating \' as if end of line marker $

I have successfully used sed in SCO Unix - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try changing the surrounding double quote to a single quote e.g. sed 's/\"/Q/'

Comment: @rob that surrounding with single quotes won't work in gnuwin32 sed. gnuwin32 sed is meant to be used from CMD not a cygwin shell. As such, it uses double quotes if anything, to surround that.

Comment: phil you should have copied and pasted from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

sed --version shows 4.2.1 and i've checked is gnuwin32's not cygwin's.

This creates a file a.a with a quote in it

```
C:\blah>copy con a.a
"^Z
Overwrite a.a? (Yes/No/All): y
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\blah>cat a.a
"
C:\blah>sed "s/\"/Q/" a.a
Q
```

echoing a quote is a bit funny but it can be done with `^"`

```
C:\blah>echo " | sed "s/\"/Q/"
" | sed "s/\"/Q/"

C:\blah>echo ^" | sed "s/\"/Q/"
Q
```

But you don't even need to surround the whole sed replacement expression with quotes

```
C:\blah>echo ^" | sed s/\"/Q/
Q

C:\blah>sed s/\"/Q/ a.a
Q
C:\blah>
```

Answer (score -1):

I put this 
pepe "el toro"
on a file oo.txt
and with this command (using sed from GNUwin32 projet)
sed -i "s/\"/Q/g" oo.txt

I get this
pepe Qel toroQ
on the oo.txt file and some garbage files, but I think it works for you.